# How to navigate to object editing screen in flutter + redux app

Tags: flutter, redux

I am writing mobile app using flutter and redux.
I have a screen with list of Objects. After tapping one object, I want to navigate to screen where I can edit that object. For navigation I use routes and navigation reducer and middleware with push/replace actions. What would be the best approach? Should i store tapped object in my AppState? Should I navigate to editing screen without dispatching action?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the problem. Why not just pass the tapped object to the new screen? You should probably post some code

Comment: Because I navigate to the new screen using redux: 'store.dispatch(NavigatePushAction('/object/edit'))'. I only supply the route, no parameters. Should I change that? In my case, I think I'd need to have the object somewhere in my app state. Correnct me if I'm wrong, maybe I didn't understand the rules of redux

Comment: Hm... I think having the navigation be controlled by Redux is probably a bad idea. I would also not store the tapped object in the AppState. I would navigate to the new screen via `var updatedObject = await Navigator.of(context).push( /*code here to pass in object to edit*/)`. On completion of editing the object, you could just call `Navigator.of(context).pop(myObject)` from the new screen. Then the previous screen can handle updating it.